# How to use osstream properly in c++. Is there a easy or better way of implementing logging of program execution flow to a file in c++

Tags: c++

While trying to work with the `<<` operator and `std::basic_ostream`, I ran into an error and I don't understand why it's a problem.

In the code samples below, the 1st statement works for both version but the 2nd statement only works with version 1

```
*TestLog::getInstance() << "Hi this is ";
*TestLog::getInstance() << "Hi this is " << endl;
```

What exactly happens if we overload the operator `<< std::basic_ostream`?.

### Version 1

```
    ofstream logFile("log.txt")
    class TestLog : public std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> > 
    {
        public:
            static TestLog* getInstance()


            typedef std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char> > SuperType;
            TestLog& operator<<(SuperType& (*manip)(SuperType& ))
            {
                stream1_ << manip;
                return *this;
            }

            template<typename T>
            TestLog& operator<<(const T& t)
            {
                stream1_ << t;
                return *this;
            }

         protected:
            TestLog();
         private:
           static TestLog* _instance;
           std::ostream& stream1_;
    };

    TestLog* TestLog::getInstance()
    {
       if(_instance == 0)
       {
           _instance = new TestLog();
       }
       return _instance;
    }

    TestLog::TestLog():SuperType(logFile.rdbuf()), stream1_(logFile)
    {
    }
```

### Version 2

```
    class TestLog
    {
        public:
            static TestLog* getInstance()

            template<typename T>
            TestLog& operator<<(const T& t)
            {
                stream1_ << t;
                return *this;
            }

         protected:
            TestLog();
         private:
           static TestLog* _instance;
           std::ostream& stream1_;
    };

    TestLog* TestLog::getInstance()
    {
       if(_instance == 0)
       {
           _instance = new TestLog();
       }
       return _instance;
    }

    TestLog::TestLog():stream1_(logFile)
    {
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The statements as posted all "work" with both approaches shown. I *guess* you meant to use a manipulator like `std::flush` (maybe even `std::endl` which shouldn't be used anyway) instead of `"a test"` for the second statement as that would, indeed, only work with the first apporoach: `std::flush` is a function template whose type needs to be deduced upon use. Since your [misguided] implementation of the output operator itself is a template the template arguments for `std::flush` cannot be deduced and the compilation fails. In the first approach your class contains an explicit overload dealing with the type of a template instantiation of the manipulators which is sufficient to deduce the necessary template argument.

Either way, your approach to creating a new stream is **not** a good idea at all! Both of your approaches fail, e.g., when trying to pass the resulting "stream" to something which expects and `std::ostream&` as argument. For output streams there are two independent dimensions which can vary (similarly for input streams):

1. For any new type objects can be formatted in a specific way. This is done by overloading the shift operator for `std::ostream&` and the object's type.
2. The destination of characters can be modified. This is done by inheriting from `std::streambuf` and overriding the appropriate `virtual` function, notably `overflow()`.

Your code tries to change the destination of characters by overloading the shift operator. Doing so is not intended to work and does create subtle problems like the problem not working with manipulators, functions taking `std::ostream&` as argument, or attempts to change the format flags of the "stream" using the various accessor functions.

Comment: Thank you Dietmar, My use case is to implement logging of program to a file. There are multiple files in the program that needs to access the log file. Is there a good way to do it ?.

Comment: @Venky: I don't see why that would require a custom stream! You could just have a central location where an `std::ofstream` is held (you `getInstance()` function) returning a `std::ostream&`. A modified stream would only needed when something is done to sequence, e.g., a timestamp being inserted at the beginning of each line. Something like this could easily be done returning an `std::ostream&` initialized with a filtering stream buffer writing to a `std::filebuf`.